# recursive indexing failed at level 3 - for loop filter

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, filter

I am working on an animal tracking dataset and want to filter specific time periods from this dataset.

I have simplified the code to isolate the issue:

`k=1 i=1 Intrusion5_animaldata_mv %>%  filter(t %in% time_windows_utc2[[i]][[k]])`

**give me the following error: **
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `t %in% time_windows_utc2[[i]][[k]]`.
Caused by error in `time_windows_utc2[[i]]`:
! recursive indexing failed at level 3

A snippet of Intrusion5_animaldata_mv is:

```
structure(list(t = structure(c(1505965920, 1505965980, 1505966040, 
1505966100, 1505966160), tzone = "Etc/GMT-2", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), i = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x = c(26570L, 26569L, 
26566L, 26565L, 26563L), y = c(3747L, 3745L, 3742L, 3740L, 3737L
), temp = c(1850L, 1850L, 1860L, 1860L, 1860L), acs.mean.mean = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), acs.mean.peak = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), acs.mean.sd = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), acs.sd.mean = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), acs.sd.peak = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), acs.sd.sd = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), acs.fracmove = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x_fix = c(590457, 590456.9, 590456.6, 590456.5, 
590456.3), y_fix = c(7319174.7, 7319174.5, 7319174.2, 7319174, 
7319173.7)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

time_windows_utc2 is a list that contains 8 lists of 6 lists of a vector with 62 values.

```
`*List of 8
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ : POSIXct[1:62], format: "2017-09-21 05:52:00" "2017-09-21 05:51:00" "2017-09-21 05:50:00" "2017-09-21 05:49:00" ...

  ..$ : POSIXct[1:62], format: "2017-09-21 06:12:00" "2017-09-21 06:11:00" "2017-09-21 06:10:00" "2017-09-21 06:09:00" ...
  ..$ : POSIXct[1:62], format: "2017-09-21 06:32:00" "2017-09-21 06:31:00" "2017-09-21 06:30:00" "2017-09-21 06:29:00" ...
  ..$ : POSIXct[1:62], format: "2017-09-21 06:52:00" "2017-09-21 06:51:00" "2017-09-21 06:50:00" "2017-09-21 06:49:00" ...
  ..$ : POSIXct[1:62], format: "2017-09-21 07:12:00" "2017-09-21 07:11:00" "2017-09-21 07:10:00" "2017-09-21 07:09:00" ...
  ..$ : POSIXct[1:62], format: "2017-09-21 07:32:00" "2017-09-21 07:31:00" "2017-09-21 07:30:00" "2017-09-21 07:29:00" ...*`
```

Indexing the first list of the first list (thus the first vector with 62 values) works perfectly, but when trying to do it with my for loop it gives me an error.

Even if I don't use the for loop like in the example code I provided here I get the indexing error.

`>Intrusion5_animaldata_mv %>%

- filter(t %in% time_windows_utc2[[1]][[1]])
  **Gives me the correct output.**`

Comment: Hello Thomas! Welcome! Now, is very hard to help you, if we do not have access to a part of the data you are using. You need to share it with us. A good solution is: you apply `dput()` function over your `Intrusion5_animaldata_mv` object. R will return as result, the necessary code to replicate your `Intrusion5_animaldata_mv` object in our session. Just copy and paste this code into your question. For more info, I recommend you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: Thank you, I added the the first 5 rows of my dataset. (data set has 18 million records so I don't think that is of help). 

The problem is however for sure with the indexing of the list time_windows_utc2. The filter function cannot index the i and k correctly.

Comment: I actually found the solution! 

For indexing in a filter using dplyr I needed to use the 'Bang Bang' operator (!!).


`k=1 i=1 Intrusion5_animaldata_mv %>%  filter(t %in% !!time_windows_utc2[[i]][[k]])`

This solved the problem, although I am still not completely sure what the 'Bang Bang' operator does.